# regular expression not matching on javascript but matches on other languages

Tags: javascript, regex

so I've been running around regexp for a while now, and been using [RegEx101](http://regex101.com) to test my patterns, and it never failed (yet).

So I am trying to replace android Emojicons strings to their appropriate HTML image tage via regex, the code seems to match without an issue in the site above, and even works with PHP, but somehow, it doesn't match at all in javascript... so here is my code:

```
function loadEmojisInMessage(message) {
    var regExp = /({emoji:(.*?)})/g; //var regExp = new RegExp("({emoji:(.*?)})","g");
    message.replace(regExp, '<img src="emojis/emoji_$2.png" id="$2" class="emojicon" />').toString();
    return message;
}
```

at first I thought I am doing something wrong, so I changed the code to this, just for testing

```
function loadEmojisInMessage(message) {
    var regExp = /({emoji:(.*?)})/g; //var regExp = new RegExp("({emoji:(.*?)})","g");
    message.replace(regExp, 'test?').toString();
    return message;
}
```

but even this does not replace at all! (my thought is that it is having an issue matching the pattern in the string :/ )

example strings to match :

```
{emoji:em_1f50f}
```

What I am trying to do here is replace the entire string (above) with image HTML tag, while using the second match [it is the second bracket () ] for the URL string

Best Regards

---

UPDATE :
I forgot to add first matching bracket, sorry!

Also, you can test the pattern [here](http://regex101.com/r/pW3gU3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not assigning the result of the `replace()` method call back to the variable `message`. If you don't to this, `message` remains unchanged.

```
message = message.replace(regExp, '<img src="emojis/emoji_$2.png" id="$2" class="emojicon" />');
```

Comment: updated the question, i have second matching brackets